KDE Neon pkcon update sub-process error
I'm on KDE Neon and running sudo pkcon update, which is giving the following error:
Fatal error: Error while running the transaction: 
E: Sub-process /usr/share/dpkg/scripts/steam-launcher.sh pre returned an error code (127)
E: Failure running script /usr/share/dpkg/scripts/steam-launcher.sh pre

I don't have steam installed, and that script does not appear to exist. I've tried:

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt dist-upgrade

but they did not help.

dist-upgrade is to be used with the "old" apt-get. You should use sudo apt full-upgrade instead. And you may not have Steam (properly) installed now but either you had it before (and was improperly uninstalled) or you distro already has a script for it.

Thanks. Unfortunately, that gives the same error.

Try installing Steam (from the repositories) and then uninstall it. Should be something like sudo apt install --reinstall steam...

Same error. It also occurs every time I try to install anything.

Here's the thing: The commands you used should have correct any problem with packages and if the problem was/is specifically with Steam then reinstalling it should have corrected absolutely anything left. At this point I really don't know what you did to your system.
